# "Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import" on importing ..<module>

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-import

How to fix import error by python 
I ran main_nunchuck.py.

```
from ..import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
from ..import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa import milkcocoa
```

Unfortunately,Some error has occurred.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main_nunchuck.py", line 1,in <module>
      from ..import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

File structure is as follows.

```
└─/pi
   └─/nunchuck_control
       │  main_nunchuck.py
       │
       └─/import_directory
           │ 
           │
           ├─/Nunchuck
           │     |
           │     |__/RaspberryPi
           │            nunchuck.py
           |
           ├─/python_sdk
                 |
                 |
                 ├─/milkcocoa
                 |     |   milkcocoa.py
                       |   __int__.py
                       |
                       ├─/paho
                           |
                           ├─/mqtt
```

How do I fix this program.
Thank you for your cooperation in advance.

==========Postscript 1=============

`__int__.py` was created a new folder on the directory shown as below.

```
└─/pi
   └─/nunchuck_control
       │  main_nunchuck.py
       │
       └─/import_directory
           │ __int__.py
           │
           ├─/Nunchuck
           │     |  __int__.py
           |     |
           │     ├─/RaspberryPi
           |     |     __int__.py
           │           nunchuck.py
           |
           ├─/python_sdk
                 |   __int__.py
                 |
                 ├─/milkcocoa
                 |     |   milkcocoa.py
                       |   __int__.py
                       |
                       ├─/paho
                           |  __int__.py
                           |
                           ├─/mqtt
                           |    __int__.py
                                client.py
```

then, I ran `main_nunchuck.py`.

```
from import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
from import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa import milkcocoa as milkcocoa
```

It worked well as expected!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Is any of these directories in `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`?

Comment: If `/pi/nunchuck_control` is the current directory or in `PYTHONPATH`, you should probably be importing from `import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi`. All of these directories must be valid Python package directories for that (see the doc for what that means).

Comment: You should be running this as a module like `python -m nunchuck_control`

Comment: Neither `Nunchuck` nor `RaspberryPi` folder contain an `__init__.py`, so they are not "packages", so you can't import them. You must add the (full) path of the  `RaspberryPi` folder to the `sys.path` and after that you should be able to do `import nunchuck`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did not set both `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`. And, did not set `__int.py__` in `Nunchuck'` or `RaspberryPi`. According to your instructions, I will set up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
from nunchuck_control.import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
```

Comment: Any comment on why and how this should help? Otherwise it's just a random guess.

Comment: Sometimes using all the directories will help python better locate modules.

Comment: That is how I use import, but then again, I also use little modules to customize import a little bit.